# Unexpected scaling behavior on a canvas in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout, pinchzoom

I have a view in which I am drawing rectangle and 10 lines within it. I am using pinch zoom to scale the view but I am getting unexpected behavior. The lines are scaling but rectangle is not.

Can someone please identify my mistake.

onDraw() method of the view is:

```
    onDraw() method of the view is:

                Rect r =new Rect(0, 0, 700, 40);

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            float kk=mScaleFactor;    //this variable will be set by pinch zoom event and represent how much to scale
            sf*=kk;                   // this view must scale according to previous scaling  


            canvas.save();
            makeLinesinRangetwo(10, canvas); // this will make l0 lines within the width of rectangle

            float cX = canvas.getWidth()/2.0f; //Width/2 gives the horizontal centre
            float cY = canvas.getHeight()/2.0f; //Height/2 gives the vertical centre
            canvas.scale(sf , 1,cX,cY);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
            canvas.restore();
            requestLayout();                               //this will change view width to fit the expanded rectangle 
            }
```

Also when I scaling around (0,0). Both rectangle and lines are scaling. I am not getting this behaviour.

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            float kk=mScaleFactor;    //this variable will be set by pinch zoom event and represent how much to scale
            sf*=kk;                   // this view must scale according to previous scaling  


            canvas.save();
            makeLinesinRangetwo(10, canvas); // this will make l0 lines within the width of rectangle

            canvas.scale(sf , 1);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
            canvas.restore();
            requestLayout();                               //this will change view width to fit the expanded rectangle 
            }
```

Comment: I assume the `sf` parameter that appears in `canvas.scale` is meant to be `kk` defined at the start of `onDraw`? Also, you should save the Canvas's matrix before setting the scale, then restore it when you're done. Otherwise you'll end up accumulating the scaling matrices each time the pinch event is fired. Are the 10 lines actually scaling *correctly*?

Comment: @Saran
I have edited the code. Ya my lines inside the rectangles are scaling. But rectangle is not.

Comment: @Saran Also I have getting very unexpected behavior. I have edited the question and posted my problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you scale the canvas at the center, but instead of this you should  give the pivotX and pivotY the center of the rectangle.